# Can Aeron lose messages?

Tags: aeron

If I offer a message via Publication to some channel (IPC or UDP) and this operation returns a positive value (new position) that means that data were written on disk (fsynced to /dev/shm) or not? In other words... does Aeron relies on pagecache or not? May I lose data when OS was shut down right after I had offered new data via publication and received positive value in response).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can.  Returning a positive position value indicates only that the message has been written to the term buffer.  The term buffer is generally stored in a memory only file system.  E.g. on Linux this is `/dev/shm`.

Note that fsyncing `/dev/shm` has no effect as it is not backed by non-volatile storage.

Aeron Archive is the means to persistently store messages.